# How to press "Alt + [" on a german QWERTZ keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, github-copilot

I am trying to use github-copilot with my IDE (Webstorm) and running in to a problem with these shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>[</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>]</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>\</kbd>

Actually I have to type  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>   +  <kbd>8</kbd>  to type "[".
How can I type  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>[</kbd> ?

Answer (score 1):

Option + [ doesn't work.

Change to custom shortcuts using **Preferences > Keymap > Plugins > GitHub Copilot**

I chose to use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>=</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>:</kbd>

[image: Keymap]

Comment: `=` on QWERTZ keyboard is also not straight forward to press